# Dynamically Loading an Image Not Invoking jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good morning, I have an image, which if I place it in HTML statically and run (using jQuery, but JavaScript is fine as well) a '.click' event, it works fine. My img is placed in a div with an id of 'imgId'.

```
    <div id="imgId">
        <img src="Pictures/sign_here.jpg" class="overlays" id="imgSignHere" 
             style="left: 864px; top: 252px;" />
    </div>
```

However, if I create this image dynamically, using JavaScript:

```
    var sigImage = document.createElement("img");
    sigImage.setAttribute('src', 'Pictures/image.jpg');
    sigImage.setAttribute('class', 'overlays');
    sigImage.style.left = "864px";
    sigImage.style.top = "252px";
    document.getElementById('imgId').appendChild(signHereImage);
```

I cannot invoke the .click or any jQuery or JavaScript mouse click event upon it.  I am most likely overlooking something very simple, but if you could assist me, I would greatly be appreciated.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tested it, it worked. Also, `document.getElementById('imgId').appendChild(sigImage);` was incorrect.

```js
var sigImage = document.createElement("img");
sigImage.setAttribute('src', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/LI_TRk1z.jpg');
sigImage.setAttribute('class', 'overlays');
sigImage.style.left = "864px";
sigImage.style.top = "252px";
document.getElementById('imgId').appendChild(sigImage);

sigImage.addEventListener("click", function() {

 alert("Hello");

});
```

```html
<div id="imgId"></div>
```

Comment: I just didn't put the 'div' that I was appending it to in here, which has an 'id' of 'imgId'.

Comment: This worked, I should have put the event inside of the dynamic creation of the image, but didn't think of it.  So, thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to register a click handler for elements on your page. The advantage of using `.on()` is that it will attach the click handler to all elements that match your selector regardless of when they are added to the DOM.

**Example from jQuery's documentation (slightly modified for your case):**

```
function notify() {
  alert("clicked");
}

$("img").on("click", notify);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem. You are creating img dynamically so standard click bindings wont work. You can try jquery like below;

```
$('#yourdivId').on("click", ".imgId", function(){
    alert("Works"); });
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is having issues adding the image dynamically to the page. I think they're having trouble getting a click handler to work on the dynamically added image.

Answer (score 0):

The event listener should be attached to your `#imgId` div.

```js
var imgContainer = document.getElementById("imgId");
imgContainer.addEventListener("click",function(e){
 alert("I was clicked.");
},false);

var sigImage = document.createElement("img");
sigImage.setAttribute('src', 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/382167/pexels-photo-382167.jpeg');
sigImage.setAttribute('class', 'overlays');
sigImage.style.left = "864px";
sigImage.style.top = "252px";
sigImage.style.width = "200px";
sigImage.style.height = "auto";
imgContainer.appendChild(sigImage);
```

```html
<div id="imgId"></div>
```

NB: Image comes from free library on [Pexels](https://www.pexels.com/).

Comment: This might be right...I'll try it and get back to you...thanks for your input.

Comment: You may want to read this page on [event delegation with jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0):

When you add new elements to the DOM, common event's listener won't work. What you have to do is to use the .on method. Like this:

```
$("#imgId").on("click", function() {
  alert('it works!');
});
```